# C++ Pointer Reads Memory As 0

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to have two, separate C++ programs, where the first program initializes an integer and changes its value and the second program reads the value of an integer from the first program through a given pointer. The first program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int var = 5;
    int* varPtr = &var;

    std::cout << "var = " << var <<\
     " varPtr = " << varPtr <<\
     " (long long)varPtr = " << (long long)varPtr <<\
      " *varPtr = " << *varPtr << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++) {
        std::cout << "enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> *varPtr;

        std::cout << "var = " << var <<\
         " varPtr = " << varPtr <<\
         " *varPtr = " << *varPtr << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And the second program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "enter (long long)varPtr (from the second program): ";
    int* varPtr = nullptr;
    long long llPtr = 0;
    std::cin >> llPtr;
    varPtr = (int*)llPtr;
    std::cout << "varPtr = " << varPtr <<\
    "\n*varPtr = " << *varPtr <<\
    " (long long)varPtr = " << (long long)varPtr << std::endl;
    while(true) {
        std::cout << " varPtr = " << varPtr <<\
         " *varPtr = " << *varPtr << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I know that the first program works, because I've checked the RAM value of a given memory address using Cheat Engine and the value is set well. The problem is that the second program reads the value at a given memory address as 0. I've also tried to import different memory addresses at `std::cin >> llPtr;` and other addresses were read correctly and showed the same value the Cheat Engine showed.

I'm using *Sublime Text 3* as a compiler, but I also tried *CodeBlocks* and *Visual Studio 2019*, and results didn't change.

Comment: Accessing another program's memory is much, MUCH more difficult than this. Read up on [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), for starters.

Comment: The line continuation backslash is not necessary in the above code.  (Doesn't hurt, either.  Just usually omitted except in areas of code where it is necessary.)

Comment: You may want to use Boost's [shared memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html) facilities.  I'm presuming the two programs are being written to cooperatively share memory.

Comment: Programs ask to be lent memory, and the memory they are given is effectively theirs, at least without doing much much more difficult things. This will sadly never work.

Comment: Ok, thanks, all of that is helpful, but I don't get it why I was able to input other memory addressed in the second program and still read data at this memory. @eljay

Comment: The `while(true)` loop causes undefined behaviour due to no forward progress

Comment: Just because it appears to work doesn't mean it's correct. Reading memory that's not yours is undefined behavior, which means anything can happen and you're not guaranteed to get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ language has no concept of a process. As far as the language is concerned, the currently running program is the only one that exists. There is no communication between programs except through standard input and output or reading and writing files.

Operating systems (these days) do support running multiple programs at the same time  however. They implement the isolation perceived by the C++ program through virtual memory. Memory address in one program is meaningless to another program.

Multi processing operating systems generally also provide one or more ways for processes to communicate. The C++ standard library doesn't have such capability. As such, you need to consult the system's documentation to implement such communication. First step is to find out what system you are targeting.

The system may even be an API to directly read the memory of another process if the reader has sufficient privileges, which I think is what you're trying to do. However, finding relevant address is typically difficult because operating systems typically implement address space layout randomisation to prevent security exploits. Most inter process communication is co-operative.